# How to filter strings out of integer column in Excel to process in Python

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas

I am scraping some data from an Excel file and processing it in python.  However, the data in the column appear to have some strings while I need them to be integers. I am trying to sort the data but it gives me the error because it is trying to sort numbers on a string.

I am trying to count the number of murders committed by each age in the file.

This is my code to do so.

```
xl = pd.ExcelFile('Murders.xlsx')
df = xl.parse('Sheet1')
#df = df[df["Perpetrator Age"].ne("Blanks")]
age = df['Perpetrator Age']

#print(df["Perpetrator Age"].dtype)
freq1 = collections.Counter(df['Perpetrator Age'].sort_values())
freq = [{'Perpetrator_Age': m, 'Freq': f} for m, f in freq1.items()]
file = open("MurderPerpAge.js", "w+")
file.write(json.dumps(freq))
file.close()
```

I have tried using the Filter button built into Excel however there still appear to be strings in the data. This is the error/output:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

I expect the output to be ordered by the age as shown in the example below

```
[{"Perpetrator_Age": 15, "Freq": 5441}, {"Perpetrator_Age": 17, "Freq": 14196},...
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the strings inside the Excel data? Do you want to reject the records? Or somehow fix them so they will be brought into Python?

Comment: An example of input, expected output and the code you use may help get you a solution...

Comment: Can you look at the data that causes the error? This could lead you to the solution. Maybe you can locate the problem and convert the strings into integers before comparing them. (I don't speak python, though)

Comment: I edited the question for some clarity.

Comment: @WolfgangJacques I can't edit the data because I have over 600,000 rows in the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using pandas.astype('int16') as in:

(int16 since you are dealing with age, which has a very limited range)

```
df['Perpetrator Age'] = df['Perpetrator Age'].astype('int16')
df.sort_values(axis=0)

In [14]: df['Perpetrator Age'].astype('int16').sort_values(axis=0).head()                                 
Out[14]: 
83    15
62    15
64    15
27    15
48    17
Name: Perpetrator Age, dtype: int16
```

I hope it helps!